# Any python web framework with the following features?

Tags: python, mongodb, deployment, architecture

As the basic framework core:

- Request Lifecycle REST
- Routing
- Requests & Input
- Views & Responses
- Controllers
- Errors & Logging

And these features would make our dev easy and fast:

- Authentication

  Cache

  Core Extension

  Events

  Facades

  Forms & HTML

  IoC Container

  Mail

  Pagination

  Queues

  Security

  Session

  SSH

  Templates

  Unit Testing

  Validation

And really good support for `MongoDB.`

Is there any such framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [fork of Django](http://django-nonrel.org/) that supports non relational databases. For my own projects I prefer to use a hybrid: standard (relational) Django, with [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/) for entities I want to store in MongoDB. The syntax is almost identical to django.db models.

Comment: Whats the use of hybrid models. Wont that be confusing?
I just saw eve's features. But I am not sure about its templating system. Is it based on flask?

Comment: The use, as far as I'm concerned, is that non-relational databases are special purpose, and relational databases tend to be general purpose. Some of my data is relational, some of it is document based. It all depends on your use case.

Comment: What about the views in eve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda confused by the desire of a "REST lifecycle" combined with features like "Session", "Input", etc.

For a general purpose Web/API application you might want to check out on [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [Flask-PyMongo](http://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Could be a good match for your use case.

If you're looking into building a RESTful Web Service, then the [Eve](http://python-eve.org) REST API framework (which is powered by Flask and supports MongoDB out of the box) could be a good choice. You can then peek into the source of extensions like [Eve-Docs](https://github.com/charlesflynn/eve-docs)  to learn how to, eventually, integrate the webservice with HTML/static/dynamic pages (Flask style.)

Answer (score -1):

Try **Django**.. im not sure but worth trying

Comment: No! It does not support all those dev features, when used with mongodb.