# Cant import Eve module

Tags: python, eve

Hello I recently installed `Eve` using `pip3 install eve`. But now I am having `import` problems. After installing `eve from pip3`. I can't `import` it. I tried it with `Python3.3` and with `Python2.7.` When I try:

`from eve import Eve`

I get back `Module not found` error. Can you help me on this?

Comment: did `pip install eve` work correctly? Is `eve` in pipy the `eve` you're actually expecting?

Comment: Yes it did work correctly.

Comment: because for me, using python 2.7, it works well…

Comment: maybe, check that `import sys ; print sys.path` contains the directory containing the `eve` module

Comment: where will eve be installed?

Comment: and btw, if you have several version of python on your computer, maybe `pip3` is not working with your `python3.3` version of python, but another `python3` version...

Comment: no! I have other packages that have been installed using pip3 is working fine on python3.3+

Comment: it should be in a `site-packages` directory, which will be placed differently depending on what your system is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46224/discussion-between-swaroop-nagendra-and-zmo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)? You probably should as it allows to you to isolate your Eve (or whatever) environment from others, and avoid conflicts in the process.

This said, installing Eve is as simple as hitting `pip install eve`(from inside the virtual environment if you're using virtualenv).

Try issuing a `pip freeze`, it will list the installed packages. Compare the list with Eve dependencies and make sure they have all been installed (you can use [requirements.txt](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/develop/requirements.txt) for comparison).

EDIT: you might also be facing privilege issues. Try installing with `sudo pip install eve`. But again, you should really be using virtualenv.

Good luck!

Comment: Added a `sudo` option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402952/any-python-web-framework-with-the-following-features

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem for me. Btw NicolaIarocci could you please take a look at this question regarding eve.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54005786/5658251