# Abnormal behavior of python package eve

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-module, eve

I have installed the eve package on my windows machine but every time I shutdown the machine and try to load the eve package I get module not found error.

On re-installation attempt(Btw I used the latest pip version to install), I get

```
from eve import Eve
app=Eve()
app.run()
```

The error points to the second line.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-46d1b24866c8> in <module>()
 30 #     host = '127.0.0.1'
 31 
 ---> 32 app = Eve()
 33 # app.run()
 34 

 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\eve\flaskapp.py in __init__(self, import_name, settings, validator, data, auth, redis, url_converters, json_encoder, media, **kwargs)
158         self.settings = settings
159 
--> 160         self.load_config()
161         self.validate_domain_struct()
162 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\eve\flaskapp.py in load_config(self)
275 
276             try:
--> 277                 self.config.from_pyfile(pyfile)
278             except:
279                 raise

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\config.py in from_pyfile(self, filename, silent)
128         try:
129             with open(filename, mode='rb') as config_file:
--> 130                 exec(compile(config_file.read(), filename, 'exec'), d.__dict__)
131         except IOError as e:
132             if silent and e.errno in (

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\settings.py in <module>()
  9 from os.path import join, abspath, isdir
 10 
 ---> 11 from .util.paths import ROOT_DIR, bokehjsdir
 12 
 13 

 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

Moreover, I find that there is no folder "lib" but "Lib". If this is the problem how do I rectify it?

However, the code below works but runs for microsecs, not like running a back-end server with api's:

```
from eve import Eve
app=Eve
app.run
```

The settings.py file:

```
# Let's just use the local mongod instance. Edit as needed.
# Please note that MONGO_HOST and MONGO_PORT could very well be left
# out as they already default to a bare bones local 'mongod' instance.
MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGO_PORT = 27017

MONGO_DBNAME = 'apitest'
# Enable reads (GET), inserts (POST) and DELETE for resources/collections
# (if you omit this line, the API will default to ['GET'] and provide
# read-only access to the endpoint).
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']

# Enable reads (GET), edits (PATCH), replacements (PUT) and deletes of
# individual items  (defaults to read-only item access).
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE']

people = {
# 'title' tag used in item links.
'item_title': 'person',

# by default the standard item entry point is defined as
# '/people/<ObjectId>/'. We leave it untouched, and we also enable an
# additional read-only entry point. This way consumers can also perform GET
# requests at '/people/<lastname>/'.
'additional_lookup': {
    'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
    'field': 'lastname'
},
'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
'cache_expires': 10,
'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],

# Schema definition, based on Cerberus grammar. Check the Cerberus project
# (https://github.com/pyeve/cerberus) for details.
'schema': {
    'firstname': {
        'type': 'string',
        'minlength': 1,
        'maxlength': 10,
    },
    'lastname': {
        'type': 'string',
        'minlength': 1,
        'maxlength': 15,
        'required': True,
        # talk about hard constraints! For the purpose of the demo
        # 'lastname' is an API entry-point, so we need it to be unique.
        'unique': True,
    },
    # 'role' is a list, and can only contain values from 'allowed'.
    'role': {
        'type': 'list',
        'allowed': ["author", "contributor", "copy"],
    },
    # An embedded 'strongly-typed' dictionary.
    'location': {
        'type': 'dict',
        'schema': {
            'address': {'type': 'string'},
            'city': {'type': 'string'}
        },
    },
    'born': {
        'type': 'datetime',
    },
  }
}

DOMAIN = {
'people': people,
}
```

So, What could be the solution to this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this issue after a quick test. Let me share with you all steps and let me know anything is different.

1) Enter Anaconda Prompt

2) conda create -n eswar python=3.6

3) conda activate eswar

4) pip install eve

5) python

5.1) import eve

5.2) exit()

6) shutdown windows machine

7) restart windows machine

8) enter anaconda prompt

9) conda activate eswar

10) python

11) from eve import Eve

12) everything looks fine.

did you forget to activate your env after restart?

Comment: I also don't have an issue until the import but when I do "app=Eve()", I get the above error.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the line that's shown to be creating problem.

Comment: @Eswar sorry, can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: if I use "app=Eve", without the braces, it works. Similarly "app.run" works but not like it should. "app.run()" should run like a back-end server, open until you shut it down. However, without the braces it runs for microsecs.. If such a problem rings some bell.. Please look into it.

Comment: @Eswar could you please also post your settings.py?

Comment: I have added the error report, settings.py and also an observation of mine w.r.t the error. Btw I did not use virtual env, but I don't see why it shouldn't work otherwise.