# Anaconda environment issues

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have installed anaconda navigator and through that I have installed jupyter notebook. I also have anaconda prompt.

The conda info output in prompt is different from the jupyter notebook output

Anaconda Prompt output for conda info:

```
active environment : base
active env location : C:\Users\***\Anaconda2
        shell level : 1
   user config file : C:\Users\***\.condarc
populated config files : C:\Users\***\.condarc
      conda version : 4.5.12
conda-build version : 3.0.19
     python version : 2.7.13.final.0
   base environment : C:\Users\***\Anaconda2  (writable)
       channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
      package cache : C:\Users\***\Anaconda2\pkgs
                      C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
   envs directories : C:\Users\***\Anaconda2\envs
                      C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                      C:\Users\***\.conda\envs
           platform : win-64
         user-agent : conda/4.5.12 requests/2.14.2 CPython/2.7.13 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
      administrator : False
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
```

Jupyter output for the same:

```
active environment : base
active env location : C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
   user config file : C:\Users\***\.condarc
populated config files : C:\Users\***\.condarc
      conda version : 4.5.4
conda-build version : 3.10.5
     python version : 3.6.5.final.0
   base environment : C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3  (writable)
       channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
      package cache : C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs
                      C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
   envs directories : C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs
                      C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                      C:\Users\***\.conda\envs
           platform : win-64
         user-agent : conda/4.5.4 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
      administrator : False
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
```

conda env list output:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\***\Anaconda2
                         C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
```

I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460907/5658251) but didn't help. I believe this lack of sync in the environments is causing problems to installing more packages. On running the same command in these environments, I get different errors(obvious). How do I change the environment in the anaconda prompt to anaconda3 as the active env. So that any installations from the prompt will reflect the same in the notebook.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have two base environments for Python 2.7 and 3.6 installed which might be the cause of your issues. Can you post the output of `$ conda env list` and describe what kind of problem you're having when trying to install more packages?

Comment: True, but how to solve this issue. I have added the output of the conda env list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my recommendation would be:

1) uninstall the older version of anaconda(in this case anaconda2) and you can skip other steps if it works. If it doesn't work, uninstall both anaconda from your windows. (control panel->uninstall or change a program -> python 3.xx or 2.xx (anaconda3 or 2 etc). you should have two there.

2) install anaconda 3 again but just one.

3) create new environment for different version python you need.

Comment: Thank you. Thought of it, but Is there any other way because I have installed many other packages later on which I needed and by uninstalling I've to do it all over again.??

Comment: @Eswar it may be painful to clean up this time. Using different environments to handle different package requirement will be much easier for future. So, the answer is: Yes, you have to do it again this time.

Comment: @Eswar yes, worth to try and uninstall anaconda2 only first.

Comment: Uninstalling the older version worked. There is sync now. Thank you. But now I have this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54005786/5658251.. Can you look into it? Been struggling with for a day now.

Comment: @Eswar yes, I will take a look, let me jump to my Win to have a quick test.